# data from jTextfield and display to the jTable and textfile

Tags: netbeans-7

i need help , im a Java newbie. i have a table and has a 3 Columns ID , Name , Age. Every Data inputted at the jTextfield will Display to the Table. The data Display in the Table will also Display at the Textfiles.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use DefaultTableModel if you want to populate your table. Create an array of your inputs and simply add to your table.

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
String a[] ={jTextField1.getText(),jTextField2.getText(),jTextField3.getText()};
dtm.addRow(a);
```